# Value not getting saved using extension attribute, For a newly added column in 'inventory_source' table

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3.3, multi-source-inventory

Value not getting saved for a newly added column in `inventory_source` table

**inventory_source_form.xml**

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="type">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">My_Source</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="scopeLabel" xsi:type="string">[STORE VIEW]</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Type</item>
                    <item name="is_used_in_grid" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

The column got added in `admin UI`

[image]

But while selecting the option and saving the value. It cannot reflect in the table.

**extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
<extension_attributes for="Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceInterface">
    <attribute code="type" type="string" />
</extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Plugin:

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="plugin_source_save" type="my_vendor\modulename\Plugin\SourceSave"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**plugin/SourceSave.php**

```
<?php


namespace vendor\module\Plugin;

use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceInterface;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceSearchResultsInterface;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceExtensionFactory;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceExtensionInterfaceFactory;
use vendor\module\Model\Attribute\SourceFactory;


class SourceSave
{

    const FIELD_NAME = 'type';

    protected $extensionFactory;
    protected $sourceFactory;

    public function __construct(SourceExtensionInterfaceFactory $extensionFactory, SourceFactory $sourceFactory)
    {
        $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
        $this->sourceFactory = $sourceFactory->create();
    }


    public function afterGet(SourceRepositoryInterface $subject, SourceInterface $source)
    {
        $sourceComment = $source->getData(self::FIELD_NAME);
        $extensionAttributes = $source->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();
        $extensionAttributes->setType($sourceComment);
        $source->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

        return $source;
    }

    public function afterGetList(SourceRepositoryInterface $subject, SourceSearchResultsInterface $result)
    {
        $products = [];
        $sources = $result->getItems();

        foreach ($sources as $source) {
            $sourceComment = $source->getData(self::FIELD_NAME);
            $extensionAttributes = $source->getExtensionAttributes();
            $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();
            $extensionAttributes->setType($sourceComment);
            $source->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
            $products[] = $source;
        }
        $result->setItems($products);
        return $result;
    }

    public function beforeSave(
        SourceRepositoryInterface $subject,
        SourceInterface $source
    )
    {
        $extensionAttributes = $source->getExtensionAttributes() ?: $this->extensionFactory->create();
        if ($extensionAttributes !== null && $extensionAttributes->getType() !== null) {
            $source->setType($extensionAttributes->getType());
        }
        //var_dump($source->getData());die;
        return [$source];
    }

}
```

Please provide guidance to fix this issue.

Comment: I think you need to add a setter (and a getter) for the new field.

Comment: @Radu I have added setter and getter. but values are not saving and fetching. please see my updated question

Comment: any reason for the two afterGet methods? also, did you create the db table?

Comment: it's a mistake while copying code. please see my updated question @Radu

Comment: Yes, I have created a column 'type' in the inventory_source table.

Comment: Did this resolved yet?

Comment: @anonymous Yes, the extension attribute is not setting the value for source, So I have solved the issue by overriding its model.

Comment: Ah that's seems to be long process. I'm glad that you get it done. I had same issue but after digging I get it done using observer itself. If you want I can provide :)

Comment: @anonymous Please provide :)  Am looking for a perfect solution

Answer (score 2):

As you've already implemented extension_attributes here's how you can save it. You need to observe `controller_action_inventory_populate_source_with_data` and get value of your field as below:

```
        $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
        $requestData = $request->getParam('general', []);

        $type =  $requestData['type'];
        $sourceCode = $requestData['source_code'];

        //Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceRepositoryInterface 
        $source = $this->sourceRepository->get($sourceCode);
        $source->setType($type);
        $source->save();
```

Comment: Above code will not work while source will save from API. Because it observe controller_action_inventory_populate_source_with_data event. Please share the code for save via API. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @anonymous Can you please help me saving & fetching those data, I am still struggling